# Sublime - Close file without saving

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

This has been bothering me for ages.

In Sublime, I know cmd+W will close a file but how do I toggle to the "Don't Save" option if I just want to close a file without saving?

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Press cmd-'d' (the d stands for for Don't)

Comment: Oh wow it worked! That's crazy, I was sure I tried that last week. Damn, I guess not. Cheers.

Comment: holyyy, it was really painful for ages and so simple to fix... Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

For mac, try:

1. quit the application (CMD + q)
2. remove the local sublime session with:

`rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Local/Session.sublime_session`

3. restart Sublime

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! I accidentally called `subl` on `stdout`, and it opened hundreds of empty tabs (one per line in `stdout`) so this was the only reasonable way forward.

Comment: Or `/home/<username>/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/` for Linux

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that the accepted answer doesn't quite address the question, but provides a workaround.

Consider the following excellent answer, which allows closing a file without the dialogue being displayed: https://superuser.com/a/1188135/73736.

In addition to the accepted answer / workaround, the default MacOS shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> works fine in the dialogue!

Alternatively, if you have `System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts: Full Keyboard Access "All controls"` selected, then "Don't Save" will be have an outline around it, and can be selected by hitting <kbd>space</kbd>, whilst <kbd>enter</kbd> triggers "Save".

Answer (score 2):

A hack would be to press 'close other tabs' and click continuously on 'Close without Saving' as mouse pointer will always be at same location.

Will take some seconds.

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu Users:**

In short: `Ctrl+W` > `Alt` (hold for 1s) > `W`

Longer version: `Ctrl+W` will attempt to close the file and brings up this prompt when file has unsaved changes.

[image: Ubuntu - Sublime close prompt]

In order to *Close Without Saving* just tap and hold the `Alt` key for a second, underlines appear on one character of all 3 options and hit `W` to close without saving. Other options can be accessed with `C` and `S` as in screenshot.